# My PC turns on my bluetooth speaker

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a laptop with Windows 10. I paired it to my bluetooth speaket to listen to music through it, and everything worked fine.

But now, everytime I turn on my pc, the bluetooth speaker turns on by itself and connects to the pc.
How can avoid this? I want to connect to speaker only on some occasion, not everytime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows (and other OSes) always pick the last used device, reason why it tries to connect with your Bluetooth speaker, that being the audio output at the shutdown time.

In order to avoid this, besides turning off the laptop's Bluetooth or turning off the speaker itself, you can also change to anther audio output before shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your make of laptop, you may have a keyboard function key combination to disable your Bluetooth, (FN+F12 or something along those lines).

Turn off your Bluetooth using key combination when not required.

Example image of HP device: https://support.hp.com/doc-images/1011/c04619892.jpg

Comment: Or simply select another audio output before shutting down. Windows (and others) always pick the last used device.

Comment: @MichaelBay that's an answer, should put it down as one & get some points (before someone else does)! SE [generally doesn't like answers as comments much either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216377/answering-in-comments)